# Please explain the following inline python code? index = [n for n, value in enumerate(self.Variable[i]) if value == 1]

Tags: python, python-3.x, coding-style

### I need to understand the following code.
The code is from a class method.
Code snippet

`index = [n for n, value in enumerate(self.Variable[i]) if value == 1]`

Comment: This is basically list comprehension. Refer here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions.
When you use the enumerate function, you basically end up with two outputs, the position and the element in the array, thus `n, value` and I'm guessing this is inside another loop from the `self.BUSES[i]` variable.

Comment: @ArjunMuraleedharan What does ```n for n``` do ?

Comment: refer to the link in the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above code can be rewritten as:

```py
indices = []
for n, value in enumerate(self.BUSES[i]):
    if value==1:
        indices.append(n)
```

`enumerate` returns a pair of (index, value at that index) for a given list. So you are testing if value at a given index is 1, and if that is true, you add the index to indices.